# CommandLine Arguments in java Help

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm suppose to use Command-Line Arguments to take user input and than use an enhanced for loop to sum.

This is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

```
public class EnhanceForLoop {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(args.length !=5)
        System.out.println(" please enter no more than 4 numbers");
    else
    {

    double sum; 
    double arrayLength = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double [] myArray = new double [ arrayLength ];

    double value = Double.parseDouble((args[1]));
    double counter = Double.parseDouble((args[2]));


    for(double num: myArray)
      sum += num;


    System.out.printf("The sum is %f ", sum);

    }

}

}
```

here is how it is so far:

public class EnhanceForLoop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(args.length !=5)
        System.out.println(" please enter no more than 4 numbers");
    else
    {

    double sum = 0.0; 

    int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double [] myArray = new double [ arrayLength ];

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble((args[1]));
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble((args[2]));
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble((args[3]));
    double num4 = Double.parseDouble((args[4]));
    double num5 = Double.parseDouble((args[5]));


    for(double num: myArray)
      sum += num;


    System.out.printf("The sum is %f ", sum);

    }

}
```

}

---

Here is the answer:

public class EnhanceForLoop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(args.length !=5)
        System.out.println(" please enter no more than 4 numbers");
    else
    {

    double sum = 0.0; 

    int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double [] myArray = new double [ arrayLength ];

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble((args[1]));
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble((args[2]));
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble((args[3]));
    double num4 = Double.parseDouble((args[4]));



    for(String s: args){
        sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
      System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
    }




}
```

}

---

Comment: You can't create an array with `new double[arrayLength]` unless arrayLength is an integer.

Comment: so, and now you can delete the superfluous code from your solution, about everything else than the loop and the `System.out.println` after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are summing up an array filled with `0.0` (as this is the default value), not the command line arguments.

If you want to sum the arguments, you have to iterate over them (=the `args` array), convert each argument to a double, and add these up. You don't need the `double[]` at all.

---

Edit: (after some comments)

In your example code of your question you are using an enhanced for-loop of an array, so it seems you know what such a loop is. So, now use the `args` array instead of your `myArray` there. Inside the loop, you do the `Integer.parseInt(...)` or `Double.parseDouble` or similar, and add the result to your `sum` variable.

If you need more than one statement in the loop, use `{ ... }` to group them.

Comment: [code]public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  int sum; 
  
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  
   
  
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  
  sum = num1 + num2; 
  
  System.out.printf("The sum is %d ", sum);
  
  

 }

}[/code]

Comment: @Mugetsu: **Don't add code in a comment** (it is not readable here), **add it to your question** (if it is needed to understand it) - it has an edit link.

Comment: I'm supposed to use an enhance for loop to sum the numbers and I know how to do when I store the numbers like:   `code' int sum; 
  
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  
   
  
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  
  sum = num1 + num2; 
  
  System.out.printf("The sum is %d ", sum);

Comment: how can i use the args array?

Comment: @Mugetsu: Put it at the place where you are using `myArray` now.

Answer (score 4):

`arrayLength` must be an integer. Thus

```
int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
double [] myArray = new double [ arrayLength ];
```

Comment: In this line: double [] myArray = new double [ arrayLength ];
the constructor for an array takes only ints as argument.
cast it to an int

Comment: Thanks, I fix that but unfortunately another problem appeared: when I compile the sum was 0.000000

Answer (score 3):

It's also important to remember to think about the flow of your code:

You initialize an array.
You sum the values in the array.

You never added values to the array, so you will always be summing a bunch of zeros.

Comment: can you help me add with the enhance for loop